# Finding staircase like structure in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find a staircase like (right to left) structure in a numpy array. I have a code solving this in a for-loop, but there must be a smarter solution using numpy ufunctions (?)

```
def pattern_found(sts):
    z = 0
    for i in range(sts.shape[0]): 
        x = np.argmax(sts[i, z:])
        z += x
        if not x: 
            return False
    return True


states = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
print(pattern_found(states)) # stair found going from right to left

states = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

print(pattern_found(states)) # no stair found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can vectorize efficiently, this task is inherently iterative.

You can however simplify the logic to only walk horizontally with a maximum of N cells tested for a (M, N) array.

Optionally, you can accelerate computing with numba:

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)     # optional
def pattern_found(sts):
    row = 0
    for col in range(sts.shape[1]):
        if sts[row, col]:  # or if sts[row, col] == 1:
            row += 1
            if row >= sts.shape[0]:
                return True
    return False
        
pattern_found(example1)
# True

pattern_found(example2)
# False
```

##### How does it work?

we iterate over column indices, if a 1 is found we increase the row index. If at some point the row index is the array row number, we're done. Else we fail

Here is the path for the two examples:

```
# example1
np.array([[-, -, -, -, +, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -, +, 0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -, +, 0, 0]])
                                   ->True
# example2
np.array([[-, -, -, -, +, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -, -, +, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, -, -]]) -> False
```

Reproducible inputs:

```
example1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

example2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: This will return a different value than the code posted in the question for example for `[[0, 1], [1, 1]]`. Which may be what the OP actually wanted.

Comment: @bb1 thanks for your comment, however both give `False` with this example (since the first 1 in row 0 is already at the end, there is no stairs). Or maybe I misunderstood your comment

Comment: My mistake, I meant the array `[[1, 0], [1, 1]]`, or even `[[1, 1], [1, 1]]`.

Comment: @bb1 indeed, this seems to be an incorrect behavior in OP's code. Thanks!